# Automating OpenOffice Installation

Tags: linux, windows, openoffice, wget

I am attempting to write a shell script which will download the latest version of OpenOffice using `wget`, and then use the command-line to install the application. I have seen that installing the application is easy, but getting the latest version of OpenOffice is quite difficult.

**Note:** When I am referring to the latest version, I am not referring to 4.0.0 or 4.0.1, etc..., I am referring to whatever version of OO which is the latest at the time of install, without having to change the shell script.

I can use `wget` to fetch the latest from SourceForge:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/latest/download
```

... however, it does not fetch the correct file.

Using the browser on Windows 7 x64 will fetch `Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.0_Win_x86_install_en-US.exe`, but wget will fetch `OOo_3.3.0_Win_x86_install_en-US_20110219.iso`.

How can I use wget to fetch the correct file?

Thank you for your time.

**Note 2:** wget on Linux fetches the same file.

Comment: Have you used any other tools besides wget. Sounds like the best method would be to store the file you want to install on a network share and push updates to the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use --user-agent parameter:

> ~ $ wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/latest/download

it will create `download` file that contains direct link. Now parse direct link and download tar.gz file:

> ~ $ wget `grep direct-download download | awk -F"href=." '{print $2}' |
>   awk -F"\"" '{print $1}'`

It is not ideal way, but it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the windows version doesn't honour the redirect, you can try with the `--max-redirect` and/or `-r` (recursive) options to force it.